# how to generate multiple apk in one apk

Tags: android, android-manifest

I usd Activity-alias in manifest file to launch multiple apks from single apk.
here is my Manifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.test "
   android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/images"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:logo="@drawable/images">
  <activity
    android:name="com.mmx.mccandmnc.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <!-- Alias activity used to set the wallpaper on Home. The alias is used
     simply to have a different label. -->
   <activity-alias android:name="WallpaperActivity"
    android:targetActivity="LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_set_wallpaper">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity-alias>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

but i want to one of this activities (alias activity) install on Internal storage (phone memory) and other install on external storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build multiple apks, so they can be installed in different places, you need to physically produce multiple apps.

Alias-activity is not about multiple apks - it's simply another way to provide multiple activities within a single apk.

Comment: do you know about service and broadcast receiver?